# How to use ViewPager slideshow images and videos with different slide time duration in android?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I am looking for a solution to create a slider show in android. I want to mix the video and image with it with different time duration like each item having own time duration like 10 secs or 20 secs. I only found how to create a image only slider show.

Answer (score 0):

You can register `OnPageChangeCallback` and on every `onPageSelected(psoition : Int)` you can check for the `position < adapter.itemCount` and use `viewPager.currentItem = position + 1` or `viewPager.currentItem = 0` when you have reached the last item.

For the `CountDownTimer` you can use the time whatever you want like you can hard code it to 20 sec or you can use `adapter` to get the current item, check for the type, fetch the video duration with the `MediaMetadataRetriever` class. Do whatever fits your requirement.